# Grails/Groovy NullPointerException

Tags: java, grails, groovy

Here I have a Domain class called profile and Profile Controller and Profile Service.

I' trying to pass some parameters from form along with picture and user id, but while doing so I get the error message,

```
    URI: /blog-dwit/profile/edit      
    Class:java.lang.NullPointerException
    Message:Cannot set property 'picture' on null object
```

**Profile Domain**

package blog.dwit

class Profile {

```
    String name;
    String phone;
    String about;
    byte [] picture
    String type


    static belongsTo = [User]

    static constraints = {

        name size: 1..50;
        phone size: 10..15
        about size: 1..250
        picture( nullable: true,  maxSize:1073741824)
        type (nullable: true)


    }
}
```

**Profile Controller**

```
package blog.dwit

class ProfileController {

    def profileService

    def index() {

        render (view: 'profile')
    }


    def edit() {
        println(session.user)
        def userId = profileService.editProfile(params, session.user, request.getFile('picture'))


        if (userId) {


            flash.updatemessage = "Profile Updated"
            redirect(action: index())

        } else {
            flash.updatemessage ="Could not update profile"
            redirect(action: index())
        }
    } 
}
```

**ProfileService Class**

```
    package blog.dwit

class ProfileService {

   def editProfile(def params, def userId, def f){


       def user = User.get(userId)

       if(user?.profile)
       {
           def profile = new Profile(params )

           user.profile = profile
       }

       user.profile.picture = f.bytes
       user.profile.type = f.contentType
       user.profile.properties = params


       return user.save(flush:true)

   }
}
```

Comment: `byte [] picture = new bytes[SIZE];`?  Is your `profile` object `null`?  If so, then you can't access `picture`.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc I'm trying to save the inputs from the form. Why do I need to `byte [] picture = new bytes[SIZE];?` do this? Yes the profile is null as the user enters his profile info only after the user registers himself.  Please can you define  me in detail as I'm new to this.

Comment: Right before user.profile.picture = f.bytes,  do a println on user.profile  - is it printing null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your block for

```
if(user?.profile)
{
    def profile = new Profile(params )

    user.profile = profile
}
```

will replace the `profile` on the `user` instance if there already exists a `profile`. If the `user` doesn't have a `profile`, you don't create one, but then proceed to try to assign values to it.

You want to flip your if statement to `if (!user?.profile)` so a `profile` is assigned when it doesn't exist.